# Data binding not working in Selectbox view template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**My View Code file settings.html:**

```
<select ng-model="language" ng-options="item.ID as item.NAME for item in allLanguages">
```

Below is the code in my controller JS file.

```
var app = angular.module('index.controllers', ['ionic']);

app.run(function($rootScope, $ionicModal) {
    $rootScope.allLanguages = [{
            'ID': "en",
            "NAME": "English"
        }, {
            'ID': "ta-IN",
            "NAME": "Tamil"
        }];

    $rootScope.language = $rootScope.allLanguages[1];

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/settings.html', {
       scope: $rootScope,
       animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
       $rootScope.modal = modal;
    });


    $rootScope.showSettings = function() {
        $rootScope.modal.show();
    }

    $rootScope.closeSettingsModal = function() {
        // always empty object here
        console.log("Lang:" + JSON.stringify($rootScope.language));

        $rootScope.modal.hide();
    }
}
```

QUESTION:

The allLanguages object array which is assigned to the rootScope is accessed by the template view file defined as settings.html. Values are populated in the select box using that array. so this confirms one way of data binding is working fine.

But in my code $rootScope.language is always empty. The updated value is not present in it. what I am doing wrong?

**PS:** This code is part of a large app and so it's difficult to isolate it to create a fiddle and reproduce the error.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if you are showing all of your HTML or not, but you do need a closing </select> tag. I tried an example using $scope rather than $rootScope and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing a dot. Since there are probably layers of Scopes between $rootScope and your ng-model directive. The ng-model will create the "language" variable on the first scope it encounters and won't delegate up to the $rootScope to search. If my guess is right solution is easy and requires only an object attached to $rootScope to which you will attach the language variable.

`$rootScope.someObject = {
   language: ''
}`

and use it in template like this `ng-model="someObject.language"`

Comment: Can you please explain on this? $rootScope.someObject corresponds to which part of my code?

Comment: If the scopes wont delegate to the higher level, I am wondering how the one way binding of setting the value works?

Comment: Instead of just putting the variable on $rootScope `$rootScope.language = $rootScope.allLanguages[0]`, first wrap it in an object and only then put the wrapper object on the $rootScope.

Comment: This is the part which is currently working for me. the current way of binding works as mentioned in the question. Even if we do this, how could it guarantee that the new object is attached to the rootScope?

Comment: It works just like the way javascript prototypes work.

Comment: Can you explain why you are first assigning some kind of object to the `language` variable in the $rootScope and then provide it as model for ng-model directive?

Comment: Great. After changing as per your suggestion, it works now as required. May I know the reason for this requirement of having the modal? I used it directly to rootScope as it worked for other model values in other examples.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Are you asking why do we need the wrapper object?

Comment: Yes, correct. Why we need to put inside an wrapper?

Comment: We need this because your directive is not directly inside the $rootScope. Between the $rootScope and directive there are probably many scopes. When you just want to read a variable javascript will search on the first object (scope in this case) and if it won't find it there it will go up the prototype chain until it finds it or fails. This is not what happens when you want to write to a variable (and you want cause you use ng-model), the variable will be created on the first object and it doesn't matter if it exist or not. You have to use a dot notation to initiate the delegation process.

Comment: It's hard to explain with the comments length restriction, but you can read how the delegation works in javascript and you will understand the problem since AngularJS directly uses prototypes in the scope relationships.